# twitter bootstrap dynamic show modal - too much recursion error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have jQuery v1.8.3 and  twitter-bootstrap v2.2.1

I want to create a function to dynamically display the message.

```js
function showMsg(header, text, closeFunc) {
    var randId = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000);

    var dialog = '<div id="modal_' + randId + '" class="modal hide fade">';
    dialog += '<div class="modal-header">';
    dialog += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
    dialog += '<h3>' + header + '</h3>';
    dialog += '</div>';
    dialog += '<div class="modal-body">';
    dialog += text;
    dialog += '</div>';
    dialog += '<div class="modal-footer">';
    dialog += '<button id="modalBtn_' + randId + '" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>';
    dialog += '</div>';
    dialog += '</div>'; 

    $('body').append(dialog);

    var modal = $('#modal_' + randId);

    modal.modal({backdrop : false, show : false, keyboard : false});
    modal.modal('show');

    var btn = $('#modalBtn_' + randId);
    btn.click(function(){
       closeFunc();
       modal.modal('hide');     
    });

}
```

But after display more than 3 these messages at once I get an error in Jquery: `too much recursion`

How can I fix it or have another way?

Comment: Could you indicate what you might be executing in the callback function `closeFunc`? I'm testing your code and not seeing any errors, though I do have some suggestions for improvement. Oh, and you probably meant `modal.modal('hide')` instead of `btn.modal('hide')`

Answer (score 10):

I couldn't recreate your *"too much recursion"* error, but I did want to suggest a better way of doing dynamic messages than the code you currently have.  Namely, you could just be using a single Modal and update the content in it before showing it. That would eliminate all the overhead you're presently incurring by

1. having jQuery parse the same string into html repeatedly;
2. instantiating a new Modal object for every message; and
3. generating random id's and then searching through the DOM for elements created with them.

As an alternative, have the following blank Modal in the markup from the start. Doesn't really matter where, but bottom of the `<body>` is a typical location.  If you *must* generate it dynamically, do it outside the `showMsg` function and do it only once.

```
<div id="msgModal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary callback-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice I did make some alterations from yours by adding the fixed `id="msgModal"` to the modal and added the class `callback-btn` and attribute `data-dismiss="modal"` to the `button`.

Then the code for `showMsg` could be:

```
var $msgModal = $('#msgModal').modal({
      backdrop: false,
      show: false,
      keyboard: false
    }),

  showMsg = function (header, body, callback) {
    $msgModal
      .find('.modal-header > h3').text(header).end()
      .find('.modal-body').text(body).end()
      .find('.callback-btn').off('click.callback')
        .on('click.callback', callback).end()
      .modal('show');
  };
```

Here's a demo which outputs to the console if the footer button is clicked:

### [Plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/RHIPp8)

Comment: Thank you, its good way, but I need possibility to display multiple messages. for example multiply error msg, that not to miss a mistake. I solved it by adding a few errors in a single message.

Comment: one more question: I would like to add another button to my modal which triggers one AJAX call. How should I do that ?

Comment: @CanCeylan Changing the `.text(body)` to `.html(body)` would allow you to pass HTML strings in the `body` variable, which would be parsed and displayed in the modal. You could then include a button in there.

Answer (score 0):

Or just trigger this event :

```
jQuery('<a href="#my_new_div_with_modal_template" data-toggle="modal">Click me !</a>').trigger('click.modal.data-api');
```